# How to get the IP address of a Unix machine?

Tags: unix, ip

I need to know the IP address of a UNIX machine. I can login to it with ssh but don't know the IP address.

Can anyone please tell me a command to get the IP address of the Unix machine I logged in to?

Comment: Related: http://www.coffer.com/mac_info/locate-unix.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this code to see the IP address of unix machine

```
nslookup mach_name
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use [ifconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig) to get the IP address of any of the interfaces on the system (note that there may well be more than one interface and more than one IP address).

Start with:

```
 $ ifconfig -a
```

Comment: Some UNIX systems do not label their interfaces `en0` - a more general answer is to use `ifconfig -a`. Also, the `ifconfig` binary is not always on the `PATH` for ordinary users so they may need to try various incantations such as `/sbin/ifconfig -a`, `/etc/ifconfig -a` or login as root and try `ifconfig -a`.

Comment: `If 'ifconfig' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package ...`

Answer (score 14):

## Use this command

```
host `hostname`
```

or this one

```
nslookup `hostname` | grep -i address | awk -F" " '{print $2}' | awk -F# '{print $1}' | tail -n 1
```

## Explanation

Start with nslookup

```
nslookup `hostname`
```

then search for "address"

```
nslookup `hostname` | grep -i address
```

This will return something like

```
Address:    192.168.1.1#53
Address: 192.168.1.167
```

Now let's retrieve only the addresses by selecting the second column of text. We pass " " as the field separator

```
nslookup `hostname` | grep -i address | awk -F" " '{print $2}'
```

We'll get rid of the "#53" part by selecting the first column. We pass "#" as the field separator

```
nslookup `hostname` | grep -i address | awk -F" " '{print $2}' | awk -F# '{print $1}'
```

The last address is the local address. Tail will help us get it.

```
nslookup `hostname` | grep -i address | awk -F" " '{print $2}' | awk -F# '{print $1}' | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to `ipconfig` is [`ip(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) where the output can be narrowed somewhat. For example:

```
$ ip -f inet addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    inet 172.31.39.10/24 brd 172.31.39.255 scope global eth0
```

The interface which is not loopback (lo) is the one you want: `172.31.39.10`

Answer (score 1):

use `ifconfig` and look for the `inet` part of the output.  Note if you have more than one network card (ethernet and wireless for example) there will be more than one entry.